# Countdown with timer using python decorator

Tags: python, decorator

```
import time

def sleep_dec(function):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(2)
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper


@sleep_dec
def countdown(n):
  while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n -= 1
print(countdown(5))
```

Am trying to do a countdown function but with a sleep of 2 seconds between each output using a decorator. Currently it isnt working. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        return n
        n -= 1
```

`n -= 1` will never be reached. In fact, the `while` loop will only iterate once and your function simply return `n`.

You want to use `yield` instead.

But, it still won't work. What would happen instead is that you will get a pause of 2 seconds before the call to `countdown`, but not between each iteration.

In this use case I won't even use a decorator, but simply a default argument:

```
def countdown(n, wait=None):
    while n > 0:
        if wait:
            time.sleep(wait)
        yield n
        n -= 1

# no sleep between iterations
for i in countdown(5):
     print(i)

# 2 seconds sleep between every iteration
for i in countdown(5, wait=2):
     print(i)
```

**EDIT** If you insist on using a decorator. Note that this is sub-optimal (and doesn't make much sense) and I wouldn't use it in production code:

```
import time

def sleep_dec(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return function(*args, wait=2)
    return wrapper

@sleep_dec
# it might make more sense to accept **kwargs instead of wait=None
def countdown(n, wait=None):
    while n > 0:
        if wait:
            time.sleep(wait)
        yield n
        n -= 1

# 2 seconds sleep between each iteration
for i in countdown(5):
     print(i)
```

Comment: thanks for the wait method...but am specifically looking for a decorator method.

Comment: a decorator looks like overkill here in this example. but it works.